# Jmeter extracting values from response and sending to other requests

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I have a JSON response below:

```
"books": [
{
   "name" : "test1",
   "id" : "T01"
},
{
   "name" : "test2",
   "id" : "T02"
},
{
   "name" : "test3",
   "id" : "T03"
},
]
```

I am extracting all respective ids and sending it as a body to another request.
Other request takes it as an array of strings but when I am extracting it, it is showing as integers:

```
Currently it shows:  ids_ALL = [T01, T02, T03]
and I have to pass it like: ids_ALL = ["T01", "T02", "T03"]

Note: I am suffixing _ALL to get all ids.
```

Since it is not passing the array as string, I am getting an error.

Is there away to extract it and put it in array of strings or way to use post-processer and then convert the array and send to other request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one-liner will extract all the IDs and generate the [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) you're looking for:

```
vars.put('payload', (new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).books.id.collect()).toPrettyString()))
```

no other extractors are needed, you can refer the generated array as `${payload}` later on where required

In Taurus it can be put into the [JSR223 Block](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JSR223-Blocks)

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Awesome! I was looking for this one liner. Thank you @Dmitri T. I will try in Taurus as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) to extract all the ids from the response.

[image]

Place a JSR223 Post processor just below the JSON Path Extractor to create a list of Strings (ids)

```
def idCount=vars.get("booksIds_matchNr").toInteger()
def lstIds=[]

for(i in 1..idCount){
    String currentId=vars.get("booksIds_" + i)
    lstIds.add("\""+ currentId + "\"" )
    //lstIds.add("${currentId}" )
    
}

vars.putObject("lstIds",lstIds)
```

[image]

You can access the list with `vars.getObject("lstIds")`

List of strings could be seen in the view result tree.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Janesh for all your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

**Another quick solution**

Add a JSR223 Post Processor below the JSON Extractor to create strings with the available values.

```
String  booksIds_ALL=vars.get("booksIds_ALL")
def lstIds = "\"" + booksIds_ALL.replace(",", "\",\"") + "\""
vars.putObject("lstIds",lstIds)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Janesh for your solution.